# Anyone know of an FTPS client that runs on java 1.3?

Tags: java, ftps

I know 1.3 is old as dirt, but I don't have an option of doing a jvm upgrade at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the 1.x branch of [commons-net](http://commons.apache.org/net/)? I checked out the [1.5.0_RC4](https://github.com/apache/commons-net/tree/NET_1_5_0_RC4) tag, modified the build.xml to target 1.3 and it compiled OK.  It might be worth a further look.

As a curiosity, what environment are you running in that keeps you locked in to a JVM version that has been EOL for years?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. The upgrade to the jvm is on the radar, but the app really hasn't changed in years and everything is working. If it ain't broke...

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record.  I believe the standard encryption stuff was not introduced until Java 1.4 (JSSE).  Hence you will most likely need an separate JSSE implementation, which I do not know if will be available for your 1.3 platform (which is most likely an IBM one since it is hard to upgrade).

Comment: When JSSE is not an option then the Bouncy Castle Crypto API (http://www.bouncycastle.org/) is often very useful. I'd be surprised if it wouldn't run on Java 1.3 as well.

Comment: I'm almost positive that Bouncy Castle runs on 1.3.